# Vis js network - align label with one letter in node

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network, react-vis-network

I have to align label with one letter (number) inside node using vis js network. As documentation says, there is `font.align` property inside `node` option and by default it's set to `center`. It looks nice when there are more than one letter in label: [image]

However with one letter it looks like labels are aligned to the left:
[image]

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong? If it's a bug, how can I get around it?

My full code (i'm using react-graph-vis version 1.0.5):

```
import React from 'react';
import Graph from "react-graph-vis";
import 'vis-network/styles/vis-network.min.css';

const ExecutionPathGraph = ({issueTraces}) => {

  const graph = {
    nodes: [
      { id: 1, label: "1"},
      { id: 2, label: "2"},
      { id: 3, label: "3"},
      { id: 4, label: "4"},
      { id: 5, label: "5"}
    ],
    edges: [
      { from: 1, to: 2 },
      { from: 1, to: 3 },
      { from: 2, to: 4 },
      { from: 2, to: 5 }
    ]
  };

  const options = {
    height: '500px',
    nodes: {
      shape: 'circle',
      borderWidth: 0,
      color: '#000',
      font: {
        color: '#fff',
        size: 18,
        align: 'center'
      },
      shadow: true,
    },
    edges: {
      color: {
        color: '#F98323'
      },
      width: 1.5
    },
    layout: {
      hierarchical: {
        sortMethod: 'directed',
        shakeTowards: 'roots',
        direction: 'UD'
      }
    },
    interaction: {
      dragNodes: false,
      dragView: false,
      selectable: false,
      selectConnectedEdges: false,
      hover: false,
      hoverConnectedEdges: false,
      zoomView: false,
    },
    physics: false
  };

  return (
      <Graph
          graph={graph}
          options={options}
      />
  );
};

export default ExecutionPathGraph;
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue and have a really dumb solution: add an empty space before and after your number.

```
nodes: [
  { id: 1, label: " 1 "},
  { id: 2, label: " 2 "},
  { id: 3, label: " 3 "},
  { id: 4, label: " 4 "},
  { id: 5, label: " 5 "}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control text-alignment within node labels to be 'left' or 'center' as follows:

```
var nodes = [
  { id: 1, label: "Node 1" },
  { id: 2, label: "Node 2" },
  {
    id: 3,
    label: "Node 3:\nLeft-Aligned",
    font: { face: "Monospace", align: "left" },
  },
  { id: 4, label: "Node 4" },
  {
    id: 5,
    label: "Node 5\nLeft-Aligned box",
    shape: "box",
    font: { face: "Monospace", align: "center" },
  },
];
```